# Get Error from chokidar when deploying on heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, webpack

I have such error when heroku builds my app. I connected github repo and deploy a branch in the dashboard.

```
Error from chokidar (/tmp/build924f9ebc/src/utils): 
Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch
 '/tmp/build924f9ebc/src/utils/status.js'
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you share more information about the issue?

Comment: Any solution to this problem @Maria ?